# ASP MVC Ajax request to ActionResult with string array as parameter

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little web application which must be finished tonight and im stuck with this problem. I'm doing an ajax request from the Index view to my HomeController which passes some parameters including a string array.

My output from the string array in the console is : ["text1", "text2"] but in the actionresult I get this as string[0] = "text1, text1" instead of string[0] = "text1" and string[1] = "text2".

Below is my code!

**jQuery to fill the string array (wrapped in onload):**

```
 var keywords = [];

 $("#menu-jesus a").on("click", function () {
        var keyword = $(this).text();
        keywords.push(keyword);

        getFilteredStatues();
        showDescription(keyword);

        $('#statue-info').hide();
    });
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredStatues")?height=' + queryString[0]
            + "&material=" + queryString[1]
            + "&keywords=" + keywords
            + "&itemsPerPage=" + itemsPerPage,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#pictures").html(data);
                showSearchTerms();
                hideSearchTermDiv();
                getStatueInfo();

                if (itemsPerPage >= 304) {
                    $(".more-results").hide();
                }
            },
        });
```

**ActionResult:**

```
    public ActionResult GetFilteredStatues(string height, string material, string[] keywords, int itemsPerPage)
    {
        var h = height != "undefined" ? height : "";
        var m = material != "undefined" ? material : "";

        var statues = db.GetFilteredStatues(h, m, keywords, itemsPerPage);

        return PartialView("PicturesResult", new IndexModel(statues));
    }
```

I appreciate any tips! thx.

Comment: so whats the problem split them on ``,`` and make array and so whatever needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your request to

```
    var data = {
        height: queryString[0],
        material: queryString[1],
        keywords: JSON.stringify(keywords),
        itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage,
    };

$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: '@Url.Action("GetFilteredStatues")'
            dataType: "html",
            contentType = 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
            success: function (result) {
                $("#pictures").html(result);
                showSearchTerms();
                hideSearchTermDiv();
                getStatueInfo();

                if (itemsPerPage >= 304) {
                    $(".more-results").hide();
                }
            },
        })
```

Comment: I'm having a error on itemsPerPage being empty "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'itemsPerPage' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetFilteredStatues(System.String, System.String, System.String[], Int32)' in 'Lore.Controllers.HomeController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters" But everything seems to be passed correctly.

Comment: checks with a developer tool if itemsPerPage is empty before to send it

Comment: Thats the thing, its not. Really weird

Comment: use fiddler or chrome console to check the request

Comment: Everything seems allright. I can even see the url and itemsPerPage is correctly filled. Thx for the help, I really need it now.

Comment: This is the url: localhost:32890/Home/GetFilteredStatues?{%22height%22:%22%22,%22material%22:%22%22,%22keywords%22:[%22met%20kogels%22],%22itemsPerPage%22:76}&_=1403026712923

Comment: change itemsPerPage to long. public ActionResult GetFilteredStatues(string height, string material, string[] keywords, long itemsPerPage)

Comment: I get the same error message but instead of System.Int32 I get System.Int64 now :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55791/discussion-between-nacho-laborde-and-nanou-ponette).

Answer (score 1):

For the model binder to pick up an array for keywords you need the URL to look like:

```
keywords=string1&keywords=string2
```

If you know know there will only be two elements in keywords then you can do

```
+ "&keywords=" + keywords[0]
+ "&keywords=" + keywords[1]
```

If there are an arbitrary number of elements in keywords, then you'll need to loop through the array and add to a string each time += "&keywords=" + keywords[i]

Comment: I don't know how many elements I may have. This sounds like a solution but not really a good practice.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bad practice, but I do have to admit that Nacho's solution is much cleaner.  I would go that route.

Comment: Upvoting this, as apart from being bad practice or not (why would it be?) it's the standard way of sending an array as get parameters.